# How do I display a horizontally-flipped arrow cursor in Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, mouse-cursor

I've noticed several applications using a horizontally-flipped arrow cursor. For instance, in Microsoft Word and Wordpad, a horizontally-flipped arrow cursor appearing in the left-hand gutter of a paragraph indicates the possibility to select the entire line:

[image: screenshot of horizontally-flipped arrow cursor in left-hand gutter/margin of Microsoft Wordpad]

I want to display this cursor in my own application. However, the [LoadCursor function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursorw) doesn't seem to have a predefined constant for this type of cursor.

How can I create this cursor programmatically, either in WinAPI or MFC?

Comment: You can use some image editor to create your own cursors to load, just like icons or other resources.

Comment: Creation of own cursors in "Paintbrush" - that's what I want to avoid :-) But if there won't be any better way, I will devote the time to this solution ;-)

Comment: There are no stock cursors for that, lots of existing cursors if you Google for *left handed cursor* E.g. the download here: https://forum.cockos.com/showthread.php?t=175387

Comment: A way is to load the IDC_ARROW cursor and create a flipped cursor.
A test with StretchBlt to invert width + CreateIconIndirect to create the new cursor : 
[Flipped cursor](https://i.ibb.co/CtNvbvb/flipped-cursor.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You're right, this is a fairly common mouse cursor style in Windows applications. Puzzlingly, it is not included as one of the standard cursors, which makes the job of application developers more difficult.

It was suggested in the comments that you could create this cursor yourself in Paint (or download one someone else has created) and then include it as a resource in your application binary, but that has some very significant downsides. Not only does it bloat your binary, but it also means that your cursor style is essentially *hardcoded*. The default arrow mouse cursor has even changed several times with Windows releases, so you'd need to maintain and choose dynamically among different versions of the "flipped" cursor just to be compatible with the default cursors, to say nothing of users who have customized their cursors or even selected a different one of the built-in themes (like "inverted"). Therefore, I *strongly* recommend against this approach.

The correct solution is to simply flip the user's current arrow cursor programmatically. This ensures that the flipped cursor matches the user's preferred cursor style. Define the following function:

```cpp
/// Creates a cursor that is based on the specified cursor resource (a la LoadCursor),
/// but has been flipped horizontally.
/// 
/// @param hInstance     A handle to an instance of the module whose executable file
///                      contains the cursor template.
/// @param pCursorName   The name of the template cursor resource to be loaded, or
///                      an integer resource created using the MAKEINTRESOURCE macro
///                      identifying the cursor to be loaded.
/// @return
///    Returns a handle to the newly-created cursor.
/// @remark
///    Note that the returned cursor must be destroyed when you are finished with it
///    by calling @c DestroyIcon.
/// @remark
///    This function swallows errors, ensuring that some cursor is always returned,
///    even if it has not been flipped. The client could, if desired, modify the
///    implementation to throw exceptions or return NULL in response to errors.
HCURSOR CreateCursorFlipped(HINSTANCE hInstance, LPCTSTR pCursorName)
{
   // Load the specified cursor to use as a template.
   HCURSOR hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, pCursorName);

   // Get the underlying bitmaps for the cursor template.
   ICONINFO ii;
   if (GetIconInfo(hCursor, &ii))
   {
      // Retrieve information about the bitmap.
      BITMAP bm;
      if (GetObject(ii.hbmMask, sizeof(bm), &bm) == sizeof(bm))
      {
         // Create a screen-compatible device context, and draw the cursor bitmaps into
         // it, flipped across the X axis, in order to create the new cursor bitmap.
         HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
         if (hDC)
         {
            HBITMAP hBmpOriginal = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDC, ii.hbmMask);
            StretchBlt(hDC,
                       bm.bmWidth - 1,
                       0,
                       -bm.bmWidth,
                       bm.bmHeight,
                       hDC,
                       0,
                       0,
                       bm.bmWidth,
                       bm.bmHeight,
                       SRCCOPY);
            if (ii.hbmColor)
            {
               SelectObject(hDC, ii.hbmColor);
               StretchBlt(hDC,
                          bm.bmWidth - 1,
                          0,
                          -bm.bmWidth,
                          bm.bmHeight,
                          hDC,
                          0,
                          0,
                          bm.bmWidth,
                          bm.bmHeight,
                          SRCCOPY);
            }
            SelectObject(hDC, hBmpOriginal);

            DeleteDC(hDC);
         }

         // Flip the new cursor's hotspot horizontally.
         ii.xHotspot = (bm.bmWidth - 1 - ii.xHotspot);

         // Create a new cursor.
         HCURSOR hCursorNew = CreateIconIndirect(&ii);
         if (hCursorNew)
         {
            hCursor = hCursorNew;
         }
      }

      // Delete the unneeded bitmaps.
      DeleteObject(ii.hbmMask);
      if (ii.hbmColor)
      {
         DeleteObject(ii.hbmColor);
      }
   }

   return hCursor;
}
```

(If you are using MFC, then you can simplify this code further with the use of wrapper classes and RAII.)

To get the horizontally-flipped arrow cursor described in the question, the usage is as simple as:

```cpp
CreateCursorFlipped(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
```

But remember that, because `CreateCursorFlipped` actually creates a *new* cursor (instead of merely loading a system one), you must *destroy* the cursor when you are finished using it by calling `DestroyIcon`.